# c# json format too complex

Tags: c#, json

```
[
    {
        "Location": "St Kilda",
        "Name": "Movie Plaza theatre",
        "Day": "Monday",
        "Session": [
                    { "Moive": "Ant-man", "Time": "11 am", "Seat": 20 },
                    { "Moive": "Bat-man", "Time": "12 pm", "Seat": 20 },
                    { "Moive": "Spider-man", "Time": "1 pm", "Seat": 20 },
                    { "Moive": "Super-man", "Time": "2 pm", "Seat": 20 },
                    { "Moive": "DeadPool", "Time": "3 pm", "Seat": 20 }
                  ]
    },
     {
        "Location": "St Kilda",
        "Name": "Movie Plaza theatre",
        "Day": "Tuesday",
        "Session": [
                    { "Moive": "Ant-man", "Time": "11 am", "Seat": 20 },
                    { "Moive": "Bat-man", "Time": "12 pm", "Seat": 20 },
                    { "Moive": "Spider-man", "Time": "1 pm", "Seat": 20 },
                    { "Moive": "Super-man", "Time": "2 pm", "Seat": 20 },
                    { "Moive": "DeadPool", "Time": "3 pm", "Seat": 20 }
                  ]
   }
]
```

Is there any way to make these data simple , so that i dont need to create 7 times to show this only with the different Day. And how to show all those data in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
    public class Session
    {
        public string Moive { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public int Seat { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Day { get; set; }
        public List<Session> Session { get; set; }
    }

    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

you can then iterate ober the `obj` to manipulate your data.

[image]

you'll then need to iterate over that too,because it's also a `List`.

Comment: static void PrintData(List<Data> data)
        {
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Location + item.Name + item.Day );
                foreach (var u in item.Session)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(u);
                }
              
            }

          
        }

Comment: I cant get the value in Session,  what i get is Moss.Session for 5 times.

Comment: again do it like `foreach(var session in item.Session){Console.write(session.Movie);}`, and it'll work.

Comment: foreach (var item in data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Location + item.Name + item.Day );
                foreach (var u in item.Session)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(u.Movie);
                     
                }
              
            }

Comment: I did that but i can only get 5 empty slot

Comment: exactly. Doesn't it work?

Comment: sry,,  i  typed it wrong it works....thank you